# TextUtils.split not working with the string separator as "^"

Tags: android

In an Android application,

> TextUtils.split

Does not split a string with parts separated by the separator as "^" but it works fine with "~"

Example:

```
String mString = "a^b^c";
String[] mParts = TextUtils.split(mString,"^")
```

Not working!

```
String mString = "a~b~c";
String[] mParts = TextUtils.split(mString,"~")
```

Working fine!

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caret `^` character is a regex *metacharacter*, and it has a special meaning to the regex engine to indicate the start of the input, or possibly indicating a negative character class.  You should escape it if you want to split on literal `^`:

```
String mString = "a^b^c";
String[] mParts = TextUtils.split(mString, "\\^");
```